# Are there special techniques to factor numbers of this form?

Tags: factoring

Suppose $N=p^2rq$ where $p,r,q$ are primes and $r,q$ have equal bits with roughly $(\frac14-\epsilon)\log_2N$ bits while $p$ has roughly $(\frac14+\epsilon)\log_2N$ bits is there a special technique to factor this form of integers?

Comment: If epsilon is small enough yes, otherwise I'm afraid you are stuck with genric field sieves.

Comment: A version of Fermat's factorization will probably work.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method works very fast with 2 factors roughly the square root, should work for 4. But I haven't worked it out.

Comment: @MeirMaor: Fermat factorization requires that the two factors be improbably close (e.g. agree in the top >100 bits) for it to work (for integers big enough to be cryptographically interesting).  Just having the same number of bits isn't enough.  Fermat's method might be able to find the factorization $N = (pr)\cdot(pq)$, if $pr$ and $pq$ are close enough, but that's unlikely